# Excel conditional formatting highlighting different cells in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting, highlighting

I need to setup conditional formatting to highlight any cells in the range that are not equal to the first cell. I have attached 2 pictures the first is how the data is typically entered and I have highlighted the range that I would like the formatting to apply too. The second picture is how I would like conditional formatting to highlight(ignoring blanks). I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work quite as I would like.

Image1:
[image]

Image2:
[image]

Comment: It would be useful if you include the range your data is in, so people answering can give exact samples based on your data

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have those numbers in Column B, with the first number in `B2` (after the column header in `B1`), you can use a rule with a formula like this:

```
=AND(B3<>$B$2,B3<>"")
```

[image]

And set the ***Applies to*** to:

```
=$B$3:$B$1000
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please accept it as the Accepted Answer by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer